# how to rotate an image or shape in cicular direction in uwp

Tags: xaml, uwp

I want to rotate an image with respect to another in circular direction in `uwp`.
The image given below will  provide the details about the requirement,I have no idea about rotation or animation which could perform this requirement.[image]

Comment: This Blog [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m-EqckhJNvI) from @JerryNixon should give you a good start.

Comment: thx.. AVK  but my need is that all circle should rotate automatically and continously.and if any body  tapped the round circle it will redirect to its relevant page..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rotate an image you can use this function:

```
public void Rotate(Image image, double angle) {
    image.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform()
    {
        CenterX = image.ActualWidth / 2,
        CenterY = image.ActualHeight / 2,
        Angle = angle
    };
}
```

To add an animation, you can add a storyboard:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard">
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.RenderTransform).RotateTransform.Angle)" To="360" Duration="0:0:1" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
</Storyboard>
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/graphics/storyboarded-animations

Comment: hi Stefano ..my need is that all circle should rotate automatically and continously.and if any body tapped the round circle it will redirect to its relevant page..